# JAVA get Byte[] nested in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

i need to get a response from a `org.json.JSONObject` (args).

```
new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

         try {
             JSONObject response = new JSONObject(args[0].toString());

             JSONObject data = (JSONObject) response.get("data");
             Object defaultResponce = data.get("default");

             Log.d(TAG, defaultResponce + "");
         }
         catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

`Object defaultResponce = data.get("default");` equates to a 10 character, `String "[B@ffc06c8"`

The following image is the args response in the debugger. i need to get the pointed out value. 
[image]

how do i retreive the value as it in in the debugger?

Comment: How did you get a byte array into a JSON object? What does `args[0].toString()` contain?

Comment: It is a response from a Socket.io emit request. i was expecting it to be a more jason with key value pairs

Comment: I don't really get your question, but the issue seems to be that you put the "toString" output of the array instance into the JSON output, instead of the data of the array. I think you need to explicitly convert the Java array to a JSON array.

Comment: Or maybe you just SEE the `toString` output, but the `defaultResponce` object (by the way, it is spelled "response") indeed is an array? Does it show as an array in the debugger? What about `instanceof`?

Comment: If you use org.json.JSONObject you are on android, right?

Comment: yes its android. @C-Otto , never was a good speller, you are right i changed the code and i can now see the array. `JSONObject response = (JSONObject)args[0];

                                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) response.get("data");
                                Object defaultResponse = data.get("default");

                                Log.d(TAG, defaultResponse + "");`

Comment: @Lonergan6275 Don't put code into the comments. Please edit your question instead!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to convert byte array to? String or JSONObject?

Comment: @Lonergan6275 I didn't ask what it was from, I asked what it contained.

Comment: It contains a String of json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got mixed up a bit...

```
Object defaultResponce = data.get("default");
Log.d(TAG, defaultResponce + "");
```

--> The Log.d prints the **reference** (defaultResponce + "" converts the byte[] to string). Is this why you think it's a string?
check out if defaultResponce is an instance of byte[] or whatever you are looking for.

Anyway, you can always use reflection to get to the field you want if the standard API doesn't return what you are looking for.